# Including extra library in Kurento custom module

Tags: c++, cmake, dlib, kurento

I'm trying to include the dlib library in my Kurento custom module.

In the `src/server` directory of my module I've added the following to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
generate_code (
  MODELS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/interface
  SERVER_STUB_DESTINATION ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/implementation/objects
  MODULE_EXTRA_LIBRARIES /home/dave/dlib/dlib
)
```

And in my implementation file (`src/server/implementation/objects/OpencvPluginSampleOpenCVImpl.cpp`) I'm referencing the headers I need like this:

```
#include </home/dave/dlib/dlib/dnn.h>
#include </home/dave/dlib/dlib/data_io.h>
#include </home/dave/dlib/dlib/image_processing.h>
```

I can compile the module successfully using `cmake .. -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr && make && sudo make install` in the build directory of my module.

However when I start the Kurento media server the logs show the following:

`Module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kurento/modules/libkmsopencvpluginsamplemodule.so cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkmsopencvpluginsampleimpl.so.0: undefined symbol: USER_ERROR__missing_dlib_all_source_cpp_file__OR__inconsistent_use_of_DEBUG_or_ENABLE_ASSERTS_preprocessor_directives_`

Where have I gone wrong here? What's the best way to include a library like this?